# The temp line shows type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub assign_sr_no()

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sh.Name = "master" Then GoTo gogo
    If sh.ProtectContents = False Then GoTo gogo

    Dim srno As String
    Dim temp As Integer
    temp = CInt(Right(Sheets("master").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Text, 4))
    srno = "VE17" & "_" & Format(temp + 1, "0000")
    sh.Unprotect "VALUE"
    sh.Cells.Validation.Delete
    sh.Range("L1").Value = srno
    sh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=sh.Range("A1"), SubAddress:="master!A1", Address:="", TextToDisplay:="Faridabad Plant"
    Call copy_from_ve(srno)

gogo:
    Next
End Sub
```

This piece of code is used to assign serial numbers to the sheet and then there is another code which copies data from the sheet to the master sheet.
The temp line shows

> error 13 i.e. type mismatch error.

Comment: What's in that cell? Have you tried splitting up that statement, into multiple instructions so that you could break & debug them individually? `Sheets("master")` all by itself could fail (that would be error 9 though)... get the string value first, then you can verify with `IsNumeric` whether it's a valid number before you try to convert it into an `Integer`, and decide what you want to do with a non-numeric value. Also, seems you could pull that out of the loop body, `temp` is constant across all iterations.

Comment: The whole excel table is empty i have this 25 columns and i have a form which user fills and sends me then i get to run the macro and copy all the corresponding data to the columns. I tried splitting it and debugging no results. There is another workbook which works completely errorless using the same vba code

Comment: As @Mat'sMug said, the very first step in debugging something like this is to eliminate all of the chained function calls. When you have a single variable assignments that contains 5 opening parentheses, it means there are at least 5 possible points of failure, and you need to break them up to isolate where exactly the failure is happening. If you've tried breaking them up, then edit your post to include that code instead.

Comment: @KenWhite I will try to solve it, thanks.

Comment: *There is another workbook which works completely errorless using the same vba code* - hence why the first thing I asked was **what's in that cell?**: "Type Mismatch" is the kind of thing that happens when you make assumptions about a cell's content. `#REF!` can't be converted to a number, for example.

Comment: Wait a minute, it's *empty*? Why then, there's your answer! `CInt("")` should be enough code reproduce your bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***The whole excel table is empty*** i have this 25 columns [...]

You can't convert an *empty string* into an `Integer` using the `CInt` function. This code reproduces the error:

```
Debug.Print CInt("")
```

You could use the `Val` function to get yourself a `Double` that you can convert to an `Integer` if you're absolutely certain you'll never ever need a value greater than 32,767. Otherwise, use a `Long`.

```
temp = Val(Right(Sheets("master").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Text, 4))
```

You should really break up that statement though, and pull it out of the loop body if it's constant at every iteration.

Also Excel >2003 has *way* more than 65K possible rows on a worksheet; consider using `.Range("A" & [ActiveSheet.]Rows.Count)` (or pull the `Sheets("master")` into its own `With` block variable, or better, use the sheet's `CodeName`:

```
With MasterSheet ' assuming (Name) property was set to "MasterSheet"
    Dim lastValue As String
    lastValue = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Text

    Dim temp As Long
    temp = Val(Right(lastValue, 4)

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> .Name Then ' no need for GoTo jumping here
            '...
        End If
    Next

End With
```

Comment: "pull it out of the loop body; it's constant at every iteration." - It actually might not be.  If `copy_from_ve(srno)` were to write something to column A of worksheet "master", the next iteration may be intended to pick up the new value.  (And "there is another code which copies data from the sheet to the master sheet" in the question makes me suspect that **is** the case.)

Comment: @YowE3K ah, sounds likely indeed... and not very efficient. I guess it's not putting that value in the last row then. Lovely meaningful names there... Anyway, made that a conditional.

Comment: Thanks @Mat'sMug the CInt to Val solved my problem. There was a lot of learning.